# <span class="notranslate"> tags disappear (Google Cloud Translation API)

Tags: google-translate

I'm trying to use the Translation API to translate some knowledge base articles, and am wrapping some code blocks in  tags to ensure they stay as they are. However, in the translation result some of the notranslate tags have disappeared.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

For example:

Input:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p><span class='notranslate'><code>Nuke11.0.exe -V script.nk</code></span></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='notranslate'><pre>import nuke\nb = nuke.toNode(\'Blur1\')\nnuke.tprint(\'Hello world\')\n</pre></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Translated text:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p><span class="notranslate"><code>Nuke11.0.exe -V script.nk</code></span></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <pre> import nuke \ nb = nuke.toNode（\'Blur1 \'）\ nnuke.tprint（\'Hello world \'）\ n </pre>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Python repro:

```
from google.cloud import translate
translator = translate.Client()
translation = translator.translate(['<ul>\
    <li>\
        <p><span class="notranslate"><code>Nuke11.0.exe -V script.nk</code></span></p>\
    </li>\
    <li>\
        <span class="notranslate"><pre>import nuke\nb = nuke.toNode(\'Blur1\')\nnuke.tprint(\'Hello world\')\n</pre></span>\
    </li>\
</ul>'], target_language='de', source_language='en')
print  translation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried out a suggestion from a colleague, it seems that using this instead works:
`<pre class='notranslate'>import nuke\nb = nuke.toNode(\'Blur1\')\nnuke.tprint(\'Hello world\')\n</pre>`